# Handling a Keypress in C# with e.handled

Tags: c#-4.0

I found this C# keystroke handler code using Reflector,

**e.Handled = "23467CDEFGHJKLMNPQRTUVWXYZ-\x0003\x0016\x0018\b".IndexOf(ch) == -1;**

I understand most of it except the **"\x0003\x0016\x0018\b"** part of it. Can anyone tell me what that does. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are character definitions for

```
\x0003 Ctrl-C
\x0016 Ctrl-N
\x0018 Ctrl-P
\b     Backspace
```

The \x00-- implies a unicode (16 bit) character set.

Comment: O.K. Thanks for the answer. That explains it. I wasn't familiar with the \x00.